# Expo EAS - How to add Splatters and App Icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-eas

I want to know to add app icons, splatters, etc. in Expo App like the old app.json. I have found nothing on the internet but didn't find anything. Below is my old app.json config.

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Shopapp",
    "slug": "shop_app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.example.www",
      "versionCode": 3
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can simple use same config file if you want with some adjustments. You can refer: [Keep config in separate files, select the config in app.config.js](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/config-flag-migration.md#2-keep-config-in-separate-files-select-the-config-in-appconfigjs)

Rename your app.json to app.development.json and create app.config.js with the following contents:

#### Example

```
module.exports = () => {
    return require("./app.development.json");
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is right solution , I figured i out yesterday. Thanks for the answer